# Unable to connect to OpenShift from external Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, openshift, jenkins-plugins

I followed the steps given [here](https://blog.openshift.com/deploy-openshift-external-jenkins-instance/) to connect from external Jenkins instance to openshift online broker. However when I give the OpenShift credentials, the login doesn't go through even though I seem to have the right credentials. A message "Could not request https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domains: The OpenShift Online (Next Gen) Developer Preview is here! We will not be accepting new users onto the OpenShift Online (v2) platform." is thrown. I was not able to find any relevant documentation to eliminate this error. Any help is appreciated. BTW I use version 2.46.1 of Jenkins in Windows 10. Any lead is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

are you using openshift v3 or v2?   v2 is taken down AFAIK

Comment: I am trying POC with OS V3 Online. Trying to run a build in OS from an external Jenkins.

Comment: Since I am using external Jenkins, should I not leave the cluster API URL and auth tokens to default? I am unsure of how to arrive at them.